# Peirush on Lecha Dodi

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, product-recommendation, jewish-books

I’m looking for an in depth explanation of the Lecha Dodi we say on Friday night. Is there any peirush out there that does this?

Comment: Are you looking for a book, a web article, what?

Comment: @ezra a sefer that deals with this

Comment: Are you looking for a whole book just about this, or for any book (such as a commentary on the siddur) that includes a commentary on this? Do you have any preferences for the language of the work, or its style? For example: Hassidic, not Hassidic, etc.

Comment: You may start with the commentary in the Artscroll Siddur. Shouldn't you have one, I'm sure you'll find it in a nearby synagogue.

Comment: The Siddur Matok M'dvash would be very useful to look at for his commentary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few that contain running commentaries on this hymn:

1. The controversial book [Hemdat Ha-yamim](https://books.google.com/books?id=XaYeSoPbrPMC&lpg=PA154&ots=q9tAP_T89-&dq=hemdat%20yamim&pg=PA152#v=onepage&q&f=false) ([vol 1 p. 43](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=9406#p=82&fitMode=fitheight&hlts=&ocr=)).
2. R. Moshe [Austrer] of Zamość (Arugat Ha-bosem, [62ff.](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=6132#p=124&fitMode=fitheight&hlts=&ocr=))
3. R. Avenr Afjin (Divrei Shalom vol. 4, 391ff.) Note: some of his commentary is from #1.

I have aslo seen referenced in numerous places a collection entitled 'Tikkunei Shabbat' (pub. 1641) by R. Raphael b. Yaakov of Posen which contains a commentary too, however, I have not seen the book myself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found:

[Lecha Dodi Likrat Kallah](http://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=8355&strReferer=search&PPGR=0)

[The Majestic Bride - Lecha Dodi (Lubavitch Rabbis)](http://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=4752&strReferer=search&PPGR=0)

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but the first one is a commentary on the piyut and the second one contains two discourses delivered by the last two Lubavitcher Rebbes. (The first one is all Hebrew and the second one is Hebrew/English.)

Comment: I was looking for a commentary on the piyut so the first should be great. Thanks.